# Will the Orion glass cockpit with CCD be tested with prospective astronauts on the ground during the upcoming Artemis 1 test flight ? If not, why?

Tags: astronauts, orion-spacecraft, instrument, artemis-program, training

[image: Orion glass cockpit]

Image credit: [DesignNews article: "Exclusive: A Closer Look at NASA's Orion Glass Cockpit"](https://designnews.com/aerospace/exclusive-closer-look-nasas-orion-glass-cockpit)

Will there be video cameras onboard the Orion spacecraft that registrate the glass cockpit displays and send the images real-time to Earth for prospective astronauts to interpret them  ?
And could the astronauts on the ground have a Cursor Control Device (CCD), as described in [this article](https://designnews.com/aerospace/exclusive-closer-look-nasas-orion-glass-cockpit), that would transmit data indirectly to the displays of the glass cockpit onboard the flying Orion to manage the spacecraft ?

Of course, prospective astronauts will have done many simulation flights in advance, but would not this real event with interaction from groundcontrol be the ultimate test before the following **first manned** Artemis 2 flight?

Comment: Is it even installed for this flight? https://blogs.nasa.gov/artemis/wp-content/uploads/sites/303/2022/08/KSC-20220803-PH-FMX01_0038_large-1024x683.jpg

Comment: even if the Callisto monstrosity wasn't in place for Artemis I, I don't see the advantage of trying to remotely use the on-orbit hardware from the ground.  That builds in time lags that crew inside the spacecraft wouldn't experience.  You surely use data from the flight to make your simulations respond more like the actual hardware does, but remotely operating a spacecraft is a separate skillset, sort of like operating a drone is somewhat different than flying a plane

Comment: @ErinAnne  Apart from a time lag of a few seconds, why would ithis demand a seperate skillset, with a visual reproduction of the displays and the same CCD tool that will be used on the spacecraft ?  Time delay could be taken into account, with no critical moments on this flight like a landing on the Moon.  And would not  the interaction with groundcontrol make this the ultimate "test" ?

Comment: the time lag is the critical part.  You can't just dismiss it.  Ground control interaction is already built into sims as appropriate.

Comment: @ErinAnne I meant, if ground control would have a message for a manned Orion for a flight correction at 9.32 h, the message now for the prospective astronauts on the ground would be about 9.31 h because of the time delay.. But it's great to be informed by a professional !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of what you suggest will be done because the glass cockpit won't be installed for this mission. Instead some kind of funky "tech demo" called Callisto will be flown - which sounds like it's completely a PR thing. It even has Amazon's Alexa integrated into it!

Here's the control panel for Artemis 1.

[image]

Source: Lockheed Martin Callisto [page](https://lockheedmartin.com/en-us/news/features/2022/lockheed-martin-callisto.html)

I personally found this all kind of incredible but it's real https://www.nasa.gov/feature/callisto-technology-demonstration-to-fly-aboard-orion-for-artemis-i

> The industry-funded payload will be located on Orion’s center console and includes a tablet that will test Webex by Cisco video conferencing software to transmit video and audio from the Mission Control Center at Johnson, and custom-built hardware and software by Lockheed Martin and Amazon that will test Alexa, Amazon’s voice-based virtual assistant, to respond to the transmitted audio.

Comment: We don't need no science fiction anymore !

Comment: @Cornelis All I can say about this is, ugh.

Comment: O.k, it's still amazing, thank you for your answer. But now I have my doubts about the possible commercialization of a national space event.

Comment: Maybe they'll order something from Amazon from orbit! Double ugh.

Comment: I hoped they would demo Alexa using typical queries. “Alexa, what’s the weather outside?” “Alexa, how far is it to Dubuque?” “Alexa, play Star Boy.”